# Magento-Category Custom Layout Update - Correct .phtml file not showing on frontend

Tags: xml, magento

I have created categories before and am able to have the correct custom layout show on the front end. When duplicating the settings for these categories the correct layout is not showing.

In the Custom Layout Update field:

```
<reference name="product_list">
     <action method="setTemplate">
         <template>catalog/product/canada-grid.phtml</template>
     </action>
</reference>
```

When I re-index the layout is

```
<template>catalog/product/list.phtml</template>
```

I have tried changing the setting but for some reason the layout is "list.phtml" and it is coming from the default folder and not from the current theme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have solved the problem. The Custom Layout Update Field needs to be uniform. If you have multiple store views the custom layout update xml code needs to be put on the default store view as well as the store view you want the changes seen on.